# Change Post author in Drupal 7

Tags: post, drupal-7, article

I have created an *Article* post from admin side. So in that case author of post is *admin*.

Now I want to change author of post.
How can I change author of post?
And is it possible to add multiple authors to single post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node edit page you can see a tab like "**Authoring information**", click on the tab and change the user tagged.

Comment: thanks Srutheesh, I forgot this, Is it possible to assign multiple authors to single post

Comment: No. For multiple user tagging u need to create user tagging filed(User reference filed with multiple allowed value)  in CCK.

Comment: Srutheesh , can be change field type where we  change author , currently it is auto complete field I need select box for this

Comment: Mohit, Enable user reference module and then create user reference field with select box type, set unlimited value for this filed so that you can set set multiple author tags.